# Why My test Binaries are getting copied into TestResults\<somepath>\out folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, deployment, msbuild

I am facing this unusual behavior from my Visual Studio where all of a sudden my test binaries(mytestsolution.dll) and the dependency binaries which are added in reference, are getting copied into  TestResults\\Out folder from my Bin folder and starts executing from there?

This results in my tests getting failed as my GetExecutionAssembly() is giving the path of the Out Folder instead of Bin folder where some of the dependent binaries exist?

Could any one please help me how to stop this?

Comment: Have you checked the settings for your project's build: `Properties -> Build -> Output Path`?

Comment: The output path is bin folder only. The file is getting created in bin folder, but when executed from visual studio it is getting copied to test results folder and is getting executed from there

Answer (score 5):

Little too late to the party but here what I just learned from my experiment

Env: net45, VS2017, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

When my `TestMethod` has `DeploymentItemAttribute`, it executes from `TestResults\....\Out` folder. When I remove `DeploymentItemAttribute` it executes from `bin\debug`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it was exactly my issue. I used many approaches: .runsettings, .testsettings... I seems like TestResults folder was used anymore. Then after your comment I've discovered that one of my test classes used mentioned attribute...

Comment: @KotMatroskin Glad to help, Mr. Matroskin. Say "hi" to Pechkin

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2010 creates a folder *TestResults* and deploys all relevant files in subdirectories with the following schema: *username_computername date time*.

This is the normal behavior if you don't have a .testsettings file for your solution. The .testsettings file is situated in folder *Solution Items*.

**If you have a .testsettings file, it depends on the setting of *Enable Deployment* in the *Deployment* section. If *Enable Deployment* is checked, the TestResults folder will be created and filled.**

[image]

In some cases it is possible that the TestResults folder will be created although Enable Deployment is deactivated. But in this case the folder is used only for some temporary files, not for the execution files of your tests.

For more infos see:

[MSDN - Test Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182474.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of MSTest. After the solution compiles the testrunner copies the direct references to the TestResults\_TestRun_\Out folder. Changing the compilation settings (CopyLocal) will not impact the test run.

If you have dependencies that are required but are not in the TestRun output folder, you have a few options:

1. Add references to these assemblies in the test assembly. Since the test runner uses reflection to determine dependencies you will need to reference a class in that assembly.
2. Modify the current test settings and include the dependencies as deployment items.

Answer (score 0):

Change the property `Copy Local` to `False`

1. Right Click `mytestsolution.dll` and then click `Properties`
2. From there change `Copy Local` to false
3. Build the solution and check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this behavior by disabling Deployment in the test run configuration. For example, in VS 2008: Test > Edit Test Run Configurations > Local Test Run > Deployment > Enable deployment = off.

See [Test Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182474%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more details.